# find the biggest value below a certain value in a long vector in python

Tags: python, vector, max, min

Hi I have a very long numpy vector (1000000+) `maxy1` filled with integers numbers. The vector is sorted ascending. now I also have another integer `val`. Nnow I want to find the highest number in `maxy1` below `val`
what I do is:

```py
idx = maxy1[np.where(maxy1 < val)[0][-1]]
```

but is too slow, I have to repeat this operation for 10000 times and it's taking 94% of the running time. any idea to make it faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this sort of task I suggest you use [np.searchsorted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
import numpy as np

# setup
maxy1 = np.array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
val = 7

# does a binary search
res = np.searchsorted(maxy1, val)
print(maxy1[res - 1])
```

**Output**

```
6
```

From the documentation:

> Binary search is used to find the required insertion points.

A binary search has a worst case performance of *O(logN)* (see Wikipedia [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)) as opposed to your current approach that is linear *O(N)*.